# latest version of extlib installed but not active?

Tags: java, osgi, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

in the image below I have v17 of extlib installed into my update site, but the ssjs code used for displaying version used reports 9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
(ps note the date, 20170223)

version 17 seem to be installed, but not active,

why is the osgi reporting 9.01.v08.00, and not 9.0.1.v00.17...

in the notes.ini I have two update sites and none of them contain v08
OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=updatesite.nsf,domapiupdatesite.nsf

[image]

when I type tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib into the console it reports the following.

```
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   Framework is launched.
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   id State       Bundle
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   12 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   15 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   16 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   21 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   22 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   27 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   38 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   138 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.connections_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   139 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.connections_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=269
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   140 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   141 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   142 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   143 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   144 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   145 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   146 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.derby_8.5.3.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   147 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   148 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sametime_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   149 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sametime_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=269
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   150 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.V853_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=269
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   151 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   152 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   245 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=248
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   246 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=248
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   247 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=248
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   248 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Fragments=245, 246, 247
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   249 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=252
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   250 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=252
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   251 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=252
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   252 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Fragments=249, 250, 251
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   253 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=256
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   254 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=256
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   255 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=256
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   256 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Fragments=253, 254, 255
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   257 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=260
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   258 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=260
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   259 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=260
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   260 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Fragments=257, 258, 259
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   261 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=264
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   262 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=264
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   263 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Master=264
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   264 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37                Fragments=261, 262, 263
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   265 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl1_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   266 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl2_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   267 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.nl3_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   268 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37   269 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v08_00_20170223-0757
[0FFC:0002-0F48] 2017-05-25 11:58:37
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version number 9.01.v08.00 indicates that the server is running IBM Domino 9.0.1 Feature Pack 8 and this version includes XPages Extension Library V17.